# asp.net stored procedure insert multiple pairs of data into the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, insert

I have a method that accepts  int[] (userIDs) and an int (groupID) as parameters. Then it runs the stored procedure and insert the data into the DB

```
For example:
if userIDs=[1,2,3] and groupID=4, 
then I want the following data to be inserted into the DB
userID    groupID
1            4
2            4
3            4
```

I have 2 solutions to this problem. The first one is to write a stored procedure that insert a single record into the DB. In the method(), I will loop through the int[] and call the stored procedures n times

```
method()
for (int i =0; i< userID.length; i++){
    // call stored procedure to insert a single record
}
```

The second solution is to pass int[] and int as parameters to the stored procedures and do the looping in the stored procedure.

Which way is a better solution? ( if its the 2nd solution is better, can someone provide guidance on handling int[] in stored procedure )

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason why you don't want to use an O/R mapper? 
Your example looks like server / code-behind and you can use Entity Framework (or other) to insert your new values. 
If you can't use them then I would use the for ( the 2nd in your posting) approach. But it's dangerous, because you are not within any transaction.

You can start your Entity Framework investigation here : http://www.asp.net/entity-framework. 
If you, for any reasons, are not able to use EF consider using a transcation scope for your sql commands ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/777e5ebh.aspx for starting reading )

Comment: Thanks. sorry I am pretty new to asp-net. can you briefly explain wat's O/R and server/code behind?

Comment: I added some links for O/R in my response. Code-Behind means that you execute code on the server ( like events from your controls).

Answer (score 0):

Geeeeeeeeeeeenerally speaking, code is faster for this stuff. You're bettter off iterating through your array, C# side, then calling a stored procedure to handle your specific record.

Now of course specifics will change, and this certainly sounds best handled in one big shot. Convert your int array to a datatable and then you can have some [real fun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)...

Comment: Generally speaking, that s wrong. If you exec n times you need n network calls and n execution which pretty much is always slower than one network call and one execution with multiple inserts.

Comment: Fair enough, but usually we're not just dumping data straight into a database; usually we're doing something to that data before it goes to SQL, and that's when SQL doesn't play as well as handling it in code. Hence 'general' and hence why this particular question would in fact be best done on SQL-side

Comment: I completely agree with you that some operations (string split, loops, pretty much everything that deals with single records instead of sets) is easier (and more sane) to code and maintain in C#...

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is adding rows to a database, I don't see the need for a Stored Procedure (unless that's a requirement coming from a DBA or policy).

Just loop through your items and add the entries to the database using ADO.NET or Entity Framework.